# integral conditions for continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\sin(nx)\: dx
\ \ =\ \ 
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\cos(nx)\: dx
\ \ =\ \ 
0
$$
for all  $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and both integrals
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!|f(x)\sin(nx)|\: dx 
,\qquad
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!|f(x)\cos(nx)|\: dx
$$
are finite.

I'm curious if it implies $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first pair of hypotheses are equivalent to the Fourier transform
$$
\hat f(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-ix\xi} \,dx
$$
vanishing at all integers $n$. This is not sufficient to force $f(x)$ to be identically zero: for example, just let $f$ be the inverse Fourier transform of a sufficiently integrable function $\hat f$ that vanishes at all integers, such as $\hat f(\xi) = e^{-x^2} \sin(\pi x)$.

If you further assume that $f$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, then these conditions do force $f$ to be identically zero (this is equivalent to uniqueness of Fourier series).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for